# Filtrado de Fechas en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un filtrado de fechas, el asunto está así:

Por método `POST` obtengo una fecha con el formato `"yyy-mm-dd"` además la hora con formato `"HH:MM:SS"`, la fecha y la hora son variables separadas de tipo string.

```
$fecha = "2016-08-29";
$hora = "13:00:00";
```

Con forme a esa fecha y hora quiero hacer un filtrado que se ajuste al siguiente requerimiento:

> "Mostrar un formulario sólo los días Lunes a Viernes de 07:00 a 22:00 hrs y Sábados de 10:00 a 14:00 hrs".

Por ejemplo: La variable `$fecha` y `$hora` se ajustan al requerimiento, así que debería mostrar alguna información, un formulario.

Estoy tratando con algunos métodos de `PHP` como `date()`, `time()`, sin embargo no logro resolver el problema.

Si tuvieran alguna idea o recomendación se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es la información que se desea filtrar, o en qué formato está: json, arrays, base de datos?

Comment: @Iras, te invito a leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Shaz Te lo agradezco, trataré de editar lo mejor posible mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dados los strings

```
$fecha = "2016-08-29";
$hora = "13:00:00";
```

Un primer algoritmo que cumpla con esta sentencia:

> "Mostrar un formulario sólo los días Lunes a Viernes de 07:00 a 22:00
>   hrs y Sábados de 10:00 a 14:00 hrs".

Podríamos ser:

```
//************************************
// horarioComercial(fecha,hora)
//
// Devuelve verdadero si la fecha y la
// hora dadas se encuentran en horario 
// comercial
//************************************

function horarioComercial($fecha,$hora)
{
  //Convertimos los strings en fechas unix
  $fecha_unix = strtotime($fecha);
  $hora_unix = strtotime($hora);

  $dia = date("w",$fecha_unix); // Día de la semana en formato númerico
  $hora = date("H",$hora_unix); // Hora en formato 00

  if($dia > 0) //Es entre lunes y sábado
  {
    if($dia > 0 && $dia < 6) //Si es de lunes a viernes
    {
      if( $hora >= 7 && $hora <= 22 ) // Y es de 7:00 a 22:00
      {
        return true; // Horario comercial
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if($dia == 6) // Es sábado
    {
      if( $hora >= 10 && $hora <= 14) // Entre las 10 y las 14
      {
        return true; // Horario comercial
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Debería funcionar.... luego lo del formulario lo implementas como veas. Si estás programando tras un servidor web, quitas los argumentos de la línea de comandos y los sustituyes por las variables get o post o como las envíes.

Espero haberte entendido.

Comment: Muy buena, gracias por tu respuesta @Ricardo ... Si encuentro una similar la compartiré por aquí.

Comment: nada hombre, para eso estamos. Échale un ojo al apartado de fechas de PHP, es de lectura obligatoria. Por ser algo simple mucha gente lo pasa por alto y al final uno se atasca en cosas sencillas. http://php.net/manual/es/book.datetime.php

Comment: ¿Y si defines el código en si como una función que recibe cono parámetros la fecha y la hora en formato string? El retorno podría ser una variable de tipo booleana. Una sugerencia nomás, tal vez hace más claro el código a otros.

Comment: pues puede que tengas razón @ElAsiduo a ver pruebo....